# bundle install request to do each gem install manually - how to avoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

This is probably very simple question.
Each time I do "Bundle install" in the folder of the project 
I get an error like this

```
 An error occured while installing json (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that X succeeds before bundling.
```

where X can be
'gem install json -v '1.6.6'
or
'gem install execjs -v '1.3.2'
or 
'gem install coffee-script -v '2.2.0'

Now, after I gradualy do each gem install manually the bundle install succeeds.
Is there a way to do them all in one command?
is there a way to do it in ruby mine?

Comment: Are there any gemsets for which bundler does not throw an error to stderr?

Comment: Please, update your question with the `Gemfile` content.

Comment: Try deleting Gemfile.lock or bundle update

Answer (score 5):

That's what Bundler is **supposed** to do for you.

It looks like you have a problem with your Bundler or Ruby Install somewhere.

Without more information I can only suggest that you checkout the [Bundler Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md).

Comment: Nowhere it describes my problem. what other info can I deliver?

Comment: So, have you tried other Ruby projects? Have you tried re-installing Bundler? If you create a new Boiler Plate Rails Project, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem before if my network connection was an unstable/low bandwidth wireless connection. It tries to install all the gems at once, but stalls on one of them because of the lack of bandwidth. Then you can of course install one at a time maybe, but if your connection keeps going in and out this may be the cause of your inability to install them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that some of your gems aren't getting installed due to a bug related to using SSL connections. This would then mean that gems that depend on those gems throw an error like the one you experienced.

See: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

That link has various workarounds, but the easiest is to replace this line:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

at the top of your Gemfile with this line:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```